# iOS disable programatically created buttons until function completion

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

Hi and thanks in advance for you patience and help :)

Here is what I am doing:
- I create programmatically multiple buttons that call the same function

And what I want to accomplish: 
- after a button is pressed, I want the common function to run and all the buttons to be disabled so that the function won't be called again during execution of the firs call. after the first call is ended I want to reenable the buttons.

Here is how I create the buttons:

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    UIButton *button;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    int tagForTheButton = 0;

    int yPossition = 0;
    int xPossition = 0;



    for (int numberOfTheColomn = 0; numberOfTheColomn < 6; numberOfTheColomn++) {


                button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
                button.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
                button.frame = CGRectMake(xPossition, yPossition, 64, 64);
                button.tag = tagForTheButton;
                [button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                [self.scroll addSubview:button];
                yPossition=yPossition+100;
                tagForTheButton++;
            }




}

-(void)buttonPressed:(id)sender{

    //This is my attempt to disable the buttons
    //previous mistake used 2578
    for (int numberForIncrease; numberForIncrease<6; numberForIncrease++) {
        if (button.tag == numberForIncrease) {
            UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)[self.scroll viewWithTag:numberForIncrease];
            btn.enabled=NO;
            [btn setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Have you considered the small window of time that it takes to run the code vs how fast a finger can move?

Comment: So what is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: the time it takes for the code to execute is more than 30 second because it calls a function that calls an animation function so it is not a problem of how fast you move

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be disabling it incorrectly.  The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIControl/enabled) for `UIButton.enabled` state:

> If the enabled state is NO, the control ignores touch events and
>   subclasses may draw differently.

Check that `DisableButton` is being called by adding an `NSLog()` call, & do away with the `DisableButton` method altogether:

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    _btn_sync_outlet.enabled = NO;
    _btn_sync_outlet.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
});
```

This might helps you :)

Comment: What is the purpose of using dispatch_async here. Is he enabling / disabling button in background thread.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you need to loop from 0 to 2577 for disabling a button which you already have an iVar pointing to..?

why don't you just switch off userInteraction to your entire view (or if that is not possible to a containerView which holds all the buttons)?

```
[self.view setUserInteractionEnabled: NO ];
```

or, failing that why not just haver an iVar there?

```
{
BOOL _ignoreButtons;
}
-(void)buttonPressed:(id)sender{

   if (!_ignoreButtons){

_ignoreButtons = YES;
//do your time consuming job, possibly on bg thread

//on completion..
_ignoreButtons = NO;
}

}
```

Comment: it was a mistake of mine :D the number was 6 not 2578 I have rectified it

Comment: I tried to use the second example but it didn't work